# Getting Error -> all package the same library [androidx.activity:activity-ktx] in Android app

Tags: android, android-library, android-package-managers, dynamic-feature-module

I have an application
which has several dynamic modules , which are working fine .

I recently updated compile sdk and target sdk to 31 .

Now I want to add new dynamic module which has a external different application (aar file) and associated libs (jar)with it . And this new app is included as a lib in my app dynamic module , when I try to add the implementation for the new app in my dynamic feature module , it gives me run time error :

```
[:modulename_last , :modulename_first]
all package the same library [androidx.activity:activity-ktx]
all package the same library [androidx.collection:collection-ktx]
.
.
.
.
all package the same library [some api lib]
```

What could be issue ?

Answer (score 3):

you can try to align those library version between app and feature module, because the app will not align the library version with feature module.

By using `./gradlew :app:dependencies` to find out what version of those libraries in your app module, and using `./gradlew :{featureModule}:dependencies` to check the version in feature module.

In my case, the version of `activity-ktx` is version 1.1.0 in my app module and 1.3.1 in the feature module, so I got the same error.

Hoping this information will helps you :)