# :feature1, :feature2 all package the same library [androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-library

I have many dynamic features in my project. Each one uses their own libraries. I am trying to add the library in base module. but it is giving me error.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: [:feature1, :feature2] all package the same library [androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources;Capability: group='androidx.appcompat', name='appcompat-resources'].

Multiple APKs packaging the same library can cause runtime errors.
Placing each of the above libraries in its own dynamic feature and adding that
feature as a dependency of modules requiring it will resolve this issue.
Libraries that are always used together can be combined into a single feature
module to be imported by their dependents. If a library is required by all
feature modules it can be added to the base module instead.
```

I have checked for the transverse dependencies and one of the library used older version of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`

I can not update the library. Is there any way to force the new version of the library for all the dynamic modules?

Comment: You can check my answer asked one year ago :P 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654315/getting-error-all-package-the-same-library-androidx-activityactivity-ktx-i